# Fixing the camera's left side in a 2D Game in all screen resolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I just started making a 2D game using unity and I have a resolution & cam problem.
I have a 2D terrain and i'm trying to fix the left side of the cam to the left side of the terrain. However, when I change the screen resolution to iphone 4 for example, the left side is hidden. I tried this script for the cam but it's not working :

```
void Awake()
{        
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width/ 2, Screen.height / 2,-10));
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = ray.origin.y;
    transform.position = new Vector3 (ray.origin.x, ray.origin.y,-10);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Camera.pixelRect](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelRect.html) (also see [Camera.pixelWidth](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelWidth.html) and [Camera.pixelHeight](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelHeight.html)).

You're finding the world point located at the center of the screen in world coordinates, changing the camera's viewport size based on that, and then setting the camera's position back to the center of the screen. If you want to anchor the viewport's left edge to say x = 0 (assuming your terrain's left edge is at x = 0) you should find the viewport's xMax, convert it from screen coordinates to world coordinates, and set the camera's x position to that.

```
void Awake()
{   
    // Set the camera's orthographic size.
    // The camera's pixelWidth, pixelHeight, and pixelRect is relative to it.
    Vector3 worldCenter = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, -10));
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = worldCenter.y;

    // Get the viewport's rectangle and calculate the camera's desired position.
    // We want to use viewportRect.xMax since we want to move the camera to the right by half of the view width.
    Rect viewportRect = Camera.main.pixelRect;
    Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3 (viewportRect.xMax, 0, 0);
    cameraPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (cameraPosition);
    cameraPosition.z = -10;
    transform.position = cameraPosition;
}
```

Some references:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/screen-width-vs-camera-pixelwidth.136703/